# Create full VPC using salt stack and boto.vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, salt-stack, amazon-vpc, vpc

I am able to create VPCs in AWS using salt states, using boto.vpc. But I also need to create  create (in addition to the VPC itself) subnets, internet gateways, route tables based on the original VPC that I'm able to create.

So if the VPC definition looks like this:

```
  Create VPC:
    boto_vpc.present:
        - name: dlab-new
        - cidr_block: 10.0.0.1/24
        - dns_hostnames: True
        - region: us-east-1
        - keyid: keyid
        - key: key
```

How can I refer to the original VPC in subsequent parts of the VPC config? Since I won't know the vpc_id of the VPC until it's created. Is there a variable I could use in subsequent definitions of subnets, IGWs and route tables using a variable?

```
Create subnet:
      boto_vpc.subnet_present:
        - name: dlab-new-subnet
        - vpc_id: ?????
        - cidr_block: 10.0.0.1/24
        - region: us-east-1
    - keyid: keyid
        - key: key

Create internet gateway:
      boto_vpc.internet_gateway_present:
        - name: dlab-igw
        - vpc_name: ????
    - keyid: keyid
        - key: key

   Create route:
      boto_vpc.route_table_present:
        - name: my_route_table
        - vpc_id: ???
        - routes:
          - destination_cidr_block: 10.0.0.1/24
            instance_id: i-123456
        - subnet_names:
          - dlab-new-subnet
        - region: us-east-1
        - profile:
            keyid: keyid
            key: key
```

Is there any way to use a variable in place of the - vpc_id value that would allow the definitions for subnet, IGW etc to get the name of the VPC generated by the Create VPC process?

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you accept it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use "vpc_name" for boto_vpc.subnet_present. You don't need to use "vpc_id" at least as of version salt 2016.11.3 (Carbon)

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Currently each of these state modules that used in the example below accepts either `vpc_name` or `vpc_id` as described in the documentation:

- [boto_vpc.subnet_present](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.boto_vpc.html#salt.states.boto_vpc.subnet_present)
- [boto_vpc.internet_gateway_present](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.boto_vpc.html#salt.states.boto_vpc.internet_gateway_present)
- [boto_vpc.route_table_present](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.boto_vpc.html#salt.states.boto_vpc.route_table_present)

```
vpc_name: Name of the VPC in which the subnet should be placed. Either vpc_name or vpc_id must be provided.

vpc_id: Id of the VPC in which the subnet should be placed. Either vpc_name or vpc_id must be provided.
```

---

**Original Answer**:

In order to get the VPC id of an existing VPC you can use [boto_vpc execution module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.boto_vpc.html#salt.modules.boto_vpc.get_id)

The first part of your state will create a VPC with the name `dlab-new` then you can test this from the command line
`salt minion_name boto_vpc.get_id dlab-new` which will return the VPC id if it finds a match.

Execution modules can be called within States like this:

```
{% set vpc_id = salt.boto_vpc.get_id(name='dlab-new', region='us-east-1', keyid=keyid, key=key)['id'] %}
```

More info and examples [JINJA IN STATES](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#jinja-in-states)

- `vpc_id` variable will hold the result which will be the VPC Id of `dlab-new` in this case and then you can pass it to the other states.
- VPC name, region, aws keys and others can be set as variables at the top of your state for easier modification in the future instead of go through the whole state looking for them.
- In order to get the vpc_id correctly you will need to create the VPC using the execution module because the jinja code will be evaluated first.

The full state should be like this one

```
{% set custom_vpc_name = 'dlab-new' %}
{% set custom_keyid = keyid %}
{% set custom_key = key %}
{% set custom_region = 'us-east-1' %}
{% set cidr_block = '10.0.0.1/24' %}
{% set instance_id = 'i-123456' %}

{% set create_vpc = salt.boto_vpc.create(vpc_name=custom_vpc_name,cidr_block=cidr_block,enable_dns_hostnames=True,region=custom_region,keyid=custom_keyid,key=custom_key) %}


#this line is using boto_vpc execution module and get_id function which will return the VPC id if a match is found and your vpc will be created as described above with the name 'dlab-new'
{% set vpc_id = salt.boto_vpc.get_id(name=custom_vpc_name, region=custom_region, keyid=custom_keyid, key=custom_key)['id'] %}

Create subnet:
  boto_vpc.subnet_present:
    - name: {{ custom_vpc_name }}-subnet
    - vpc_id: {{ vpc_id }}
    - cidr_block: {{ cidr_block }}
    - region: {{ custom_region }}
    - keyid: {{ custom_keyid }}
    - key: {{ custom_key }}

Create internet gateway:
  boto_vpc.internet_gateway_present:
    - name: {{ custom_vpc_name }}-igw
    - vpc_id: {{ vpc_id }} # I have changed this line from vpc_name into vpc_id, is that what you meant ?
    - keyid: {{ custom_keyid }}
    - key: {{ custom_key }}

Create route:
  boto_vpc.route_table_present:
    - name: my_route_table
    - vpc_id: {{ vpc_id }}
    - routes:
        - destination_cidr_block: {{ cidr_block }}
          instance_id: {{ instance_id }}
    - subnet_names:
        - {{ custom_vpc_name }}-subnet
    - region: {{ custom_region }}
    - profile:
        keyid: {{ custom_keyid }}
        key: {{ custom_key }}
```

This is untested code but I have done similar states like this using Salt.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks! I'll give it a try shortly. One question tho. What is the purpose of having the instance_id in the create route process? Is that supposed to be a NAT gateway ?

Comment: Hey Mostafa, thanks again for your input. I tried your solution and it looks like the jinja templates aren't being parsed. Here's the debug output from that command: [link](https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/6ccf4b62dd8cfae4bd0c0cefec9212fb)

Any ideas on how we can get this to work?

Comment: The problem was because of the missing authentication as the error said: `No authentication credentials found when attempting to make boto vpc connection to region "us-east-1"`, I have updated the answer

Comment: for the instance id , i don't have an experience in aws but the docuementation says the following: The operation fails if you specify an instance ID unless exactly one network interface is attached. docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-route.ht‌​ml

Comment: @bluethundr have you tested it ?

Comment: thanks again! I've tested the updated code. However it's still failing with the same error. The jinja template is still not being read I think. 

Here's the error I'm getting: [boto_vpc_error](https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/81bf01da5df57bd5930163141dc224f0)

And yes, you are correct that I need to use the vpc_id through the rest of the config, after I extract it from the Create VPC section. Also I think we can get away without specifying the instance id. I'll try that next after we get this working. Thanks

Comment: @bluethundr Its just about passing the data in a correct way , could give this update a try ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126140/discussion-between-bluethundr-and-mostafa-hussein).

Comment: Hey @Mostafa! Partial success. I was able to create the VPC using the latest  config. However the rest of the config is not able to read the vpc_id, which is needed for this to work. Here's my latest attempt [vpc created, rest fails](https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/342f470729b3d85c237277117234c40c)

Comment: please check my comment on the gist

Comment: Hi @Mustafa.. sorry my company doesn't allow chatting over stack overflow. Are you available to talk about this over skype? My skype id is: tdunphy2  Thanks

Comment: thank you so much @Mustafa! That works. I appreciate the help! :)